# How check presence of service if present return status else -1

Tags: services

I would need one line sh command which checks if service present then return service status otherwise -1.

I came up with following:

```
[mon@monitoring ~]# if service --status-all | grep sssd >/dev/null ;then service sssd status > /dev/null; echo $? ;else echo "-1";fi
dnsdomainname: Unknown host
3
```

I would need to get rid of noisy output and just leave the number. Cannot figure from where that is coming.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes have two outputs : one called `stdout` for normal messages and one called `stderr` to output error messages.

If you want to get rid of the error messages as well as the others, you should redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

`if service --status-all | grep sssd >/dev/null ;then service sssd status > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $? ;else echo "-1";fi`

`2>&1` redirect `stderr` to the same place than `stdout`.

EDIT:

In fact, the undesired output in OP's question came from `service --status-all`.
So :

`if service --status-all 2>/dev/null | grep sssd >/dev/null ;then service sssd status > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $? ;else echo "-1";fi`

Pipes only redirects `stdout` by default.

Comment: Yea, that what I tried as well. But the result is the same. 
[mon@monitoring ~]# if service --status-all | grep sssd >/dev/null ;then service sssd status > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $? ;else echo "-1";fi
dnsdomainname: Unknown host
3

Comment: Maybe the output commes from `service --status-all` then ? Have you tried ' if service --status-all 2>/dev/null | grep sssd >/dev/null ;then service sssd status > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $? ;else echo "-1" ' ? Note that the pipe only redirects stdout.